# Mui-datatables custom search

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

how do I add a custom search in mui-datatables which can be used for data fetched from API. can u please provide me a working example? I tried using

```
 customSearch: (searchQuery, currentRow, columns) => {
    let isFound = false;
    currentRow.forEach(col => {
      if (col.toString().indexOf(searchQuery) >= 0) {
        isFound = true;
      }
    });
    return isFound;
  },
```

in options.

note: in console, I got react_devtools_backend.js:6 Server-side filtering is enabled, hence custom search will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:
https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/serverside-filters/index.js

Or this (debounceSearchRender plugin):
https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/large-data-set/index.js

Your backend is going to return the results, so your custom search needs to be defined in the server.